# Lightroom CC - keep catalog on computer private?

Tags: adobe, adobe-photoshop, adobe-lightroom

I have an Enterprise CC subscription through my work since I need Illustrator, InDesign, Photoshop etc.  However, I have Lightroom just for my own personal photography.  I have been using 5.7 but would like to start using CC Classic.  I do not need the online components of it at all, I just want to use it as I have 5.7.

Can I simply use Lightroom CC Classic on my home Mac and no one through work will be able to access my catalogs?

Comment: Good question on cross contamination of data since Adobe really wants to push the cloud storage and data sync. Clearly the licensing is easy if you have two installs, but the data handling may be harder to understand / contain especially if Adobe changes the implementation monthly.